# Cosa vuol dire "per mio conto" in questo testo?

Tags: meaning

Nel racconto *Quell’antica ragazza* di Beppe Fenoglio ho letto questa frase con la locuzione "per mio conto", l'oggetto della mia domanda:

> Una sera andavo **per mio conto** sul sentiero al margine del castagneto, quando mi si para di traverso questa Argentina, vestita come aveva detto Marziano.

La stessa espressione appare un po' più avanti nello stesso racconto, questa volta nel dialogo tra Argentina e l'io narrante:

> Scese d’un altro passo. – Dove te ne andavi? 
>         – **Per mio conto**. 
>         – Come **per tuo conto**? Un servitore che va **per suo conto** in un’ora di luce. Sei scappato da Matteo? A me puoi dirlo. 
>         – Non sono scappato, ma per oggi ho finito e vado **per mio conto**.

Avevo pensato che il significato di questa espressione fosse "da solo", ma non ne ero sicura. Perciò ho cercato alla [voce "conto" sul *Grande dizionario della lingua italiana*](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI03/00000668.jpg) e ho trovato queste definizioni:

> – *Per conto di*: nel  nome,  nell’interesse,  per incarico,  da  parte,  per  causa,  a  titolo,  a  ragione, a  proposito; secondo l’opinione,   per  quanto concerne. 
>   [...]
>       – *Per conto di qualcuno*: a  suo  carico,  a  sue spese.

Non riesco a avere del tutto chiaro, però, se 
abbiano senso nel contesto del brano sopra citato. Non credo che ci siano spese da pagare in questo andare dell'io narrante "sul sentiero al margine del castagneto". Interpreterei una frase come "vado per conto del padrone" come "vado per incarico del padrone" o "vado da parte del padrone", ma qui l'espressione è "per mio conto". Siccome si tratta appunto di un servitore, la locuzione significa in certo modo "non sto andando per incarico del padrone, ma sono io che ho deciso da mia volontà di passare per questo sentiero"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La tua intuizione è secondo me corretta; *andavo per mio conto* (o *andavo per conto mio* - è equivalente) in questo caso significa in pratica *andavo per i fatti miei* (cioè esclusivamente per i miei scopi).

L'espressione potrebbe anche assumere il significato di *da solo/da sola* - secondo me nella prima frase potrebbe anche avere questa sfumatura.

Comment: Vorrei aggiungere che, nella mia esperienza, la forma *per conto mio* è molto più comune. Il senso, comunque, non cambia.